# Hand cursor over a link not showed in IE but it is in FireFox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a link within a div:

```
<div>
   <a href="#"></a> 
</div>
```

This div make's a box, like a button, and when i mouseover it in Internet Explorer 8 works fine showing the hand cursor, but in firefox doesn't.
Can some body help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What CSS are you using? The following should work both for IE8 and Firefox:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

More details [here](http://www.learnwebdesignonline.com/css-tutorials/cursor-hand-pointer.htm).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, the simplest fix to the problem would be to specify that the div cursor your CSS file:

```
div_button_id {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp

Answer (score 1):

Title and description of your question are contradictory. I'm guessing you've encountered IE bug:

```
a {zoom:1; cursor:pointer;}
```

If you have any other elements in `<a>`, apply above rule to them.

You might also want to set `a {display:block}`.

Comment: Indeed. I smell a hasLayout bug.

Comment: yes I wrote wrong the description, sorry and thank you. very helpfull

Answer (score 0):

The hand cursor is shown for the `a` element, which is of zero size here. Try to resize the `a` element to a suitable size, maybe with:

```
<div>
  <a href="#" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not this users exact problem, but I was just having this issue and realized it is essential to have a href, as in my case I was overriding the link click via jquery. So adding href="#" did the trick.